# How to scrape and display project links from Wikipedia home page?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to display the project links ("Commons, MediaWik, iMeta-Wiki, etc") under the "Wikipedia's sister projects" section of the Wikipedia home page. However, in addition to the project links, I end up with "Wikimedia Foundation" and "projects", which are two links I don't want. Can someone explain how I can make it so that only the project links I want are displayed?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'lxml')

for a in soup.select('h2:contains("Wikipedia\'s sister projects") + div a'):
    print(a.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'lxml')

sub_soup = soup.find('div',id = 'sister-projects-list')

print([ele.text for ele in sub_soup.find_all('a','external text')])
```

Output:

```
['Commons',
 'MediaWiki',
 'Meta-Wiki',
 'Wikibooks',
 'Wikidata',
 'Wikinews',
 'Wikiquote',
 'Wikisource',
 'Wikispecies',
 'Wikiversity',
 'Wikivoyage',
 'Wiktionary']
```

The code you have posted is also printing empty strings:

```py
l = []

for a in soup.select('h2:contains("Wikipedia\'s sister projects") + div a'):
    l.append(a.text)
print(l)
```

output:

```
['Wikimedia Foundation',
 'projects',
 '',
 'Commons',
 '',
 'MediaWiki',
 '',
 'Meta-Wiki',
 '',
 'Wikibooks',
 '',
 'Wikidata',
 '',
 'Wikinews',
 '',
 'Wikiquote',
 '',
 'Wikisource',
 '',
 'Wikispecies',
 '',
 'Wikiversity',
 '',
 'Wikivoyage',
 '',
 'Wiktionary']
```

Comment: https://github.com/neqkir/wikisource-scraper

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understand your question in the correct way: you should select the more narrow division in html:

```
for a in soup.findAll('div', {"id":"sister-projects-list"}):   
    for b in a.findAll('a'):                                         
        print(b.text)
        print(b.get('href'))
```

This code will give you text and a links in that division.